# Facebook CrashReporter Error detected api facebook-business-php

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I started with facebook business sdk for php. Was following this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started/ installed without trouble, then tried testing as they instructed, created src/test.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;

$app_id = "{app-id}";
$app_secret = "{appsecret}";
$access_token = "{access-token}";
$account_id = "act_{{adaccount-id}}";

Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

$account = new AdAccount($account_id);
$cursor = $account->getCampaigns();

// Loop over objects
foreach ($cursor as $campaign) {
  echo $campaign->{CampaignFields::NAME}.PHP_EOL;
}

filled in the required values. and ran the file. Getting this:

FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Enabled

FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Error detected!
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to FacebookAds\CrashReporter::buildParamsFromException() must be an instance of Throwable, instance of ErrorException given, called in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/CrashReporter.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/CrashReporter.php on line 167
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Didnt find much by searching. Can anyone please help?